# Prove $\frac{1-\sin(2A)}{\cos(2A)}=\frac{1-\tan A}{1+\tan A}$

Tags: trigonometry

How would I prove the following double angle identity?

$$\frac{1-\sin(2A)}{\cos(2A)}=\frac{1-\tan A}{1+\tan A}$$

My work thus far is

$$\frac{1-2\sin A\cos A}{\cos^2A-\sin^2A}$$

$$\frac{1-2\sin A\cos A}{(\cos A+\sin A)(\cos A-\sin A)}$$

Sadly I am stuck.

Comment: In the top line, do you mean $1-\sin(2A)$, instead of $1-2\sin A$? If not, you've made an error in your first step.

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/161783) for how to typeset common math expressions with LaTeX, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting.

Comment: Yes I meant 1-sin(2A).

Comment: Fixed.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: When you have sines and cosines and you want tangents, try dividing by cosine.

Comment: I know this is hard for people just starting out, but remember to work from both sides. Don't try and go from left --> right. You should go from Left --> Simple and from Right --> Simple. And then see if Left-Simple is the same as the Right-Simple. If it is, QED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{1-2\sin A\cos A}{\cos^2A-\sin^2A}$$

$$=\frac{\sin^2A+\cos^2A-2\sin A\cos A}{(\cos A+\sin A)(\cos A-\sin A)}$$

$$=\frac{(\cos A-\sin A)^2}{(\cos A+\sin A)(\cos A-\sin A)}$$

$$=\frac{\cos A-\sin A}{\cos A+\sin A}$$ assuming ${\cos A-\sin A} ≠ 0$

$$=\frac{1-\tan A}{1 +\tan A}$$ assuming ${\cos A} ≠ 0$

Comment: Thanks for your excellent response.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1-\sin(2A)}{\cos(2A)}
&=\frac{1-2\sin(A)\cos(A)}{\cos^2(A)-\sin^2(A)}\tag{1}\\
&=\frac{\sec^2(A)-2\tan(A)}{1-\tan^2(A)}\tag{2}\\
&=\frac{1+\tan^2(A)-2\tan(A)}{1-\tan^2(A)}\tag{3}\\
&=\frac{(1-\tan(A))^2}{1-\tan^2(A)}\tag{4}\\
&=\frac{1-\tan(A)}{1+\tan(A)}\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$

1. double angle formulas
2. multiply numerator and denominator by $\sec^2(A)$
3. $\sec^2(A)=1+\tan^2(A)$
4. collect square of a difference
5. cancel $1-\tan(A)$ from numerator and denominator

Answer (score 0):

You could first write the right hand side of your identity as ${1-{\sin A\over \cos A}\over 1+{\sin A\over\cos A}}$. Multiply top and bottom by $\cos A$:

$$
{1-{\sin A\over \cos A}\over 1+{\sin A\over\cos A}}
={1-{\sin A\over \cos A}\over 1+{\sin A\over\cos A}}\cdot{\cos A\over\cos A}
={\cos A-{\sin A\over \cos A}\cdot\cos A\over \cos A+{\sin A\over\cos A}\cdot \cos A} 
= 
{\cos A-\sin A\over \cos A+\sin A}.
$$
Multiply top and bottom by $\cos A-\sin A$ :
$$
{\cos A-\sin A\over \cos A+\sin A}=
{\cos A-\sin A\over \cos A+\sin A}\cdot{\cos A-\sin A\over \cos A-\sin A}
={\cos^2 A+\sin^2 A-2\cos A\sin A\over \cos^2 A-\sin^2 A}.
$$
Finally apply the Pythagorean Identity and the Double Angle formulas to get what you want.

Comment: I see now there is alternate way of proving the identity.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea in this case to rewrite $\tan A=\frac{\sin A}{\cos A}$, then simplify the expression on the right, multiplying top and bottom by $\cos A$ to clear the "little fractions" from the "big fraction".

That will give you $$\frac{\cos A-\sin A}{\cos A+\sin A}$$ on the right hand side. Then, rewriting the left hand side denominator as $(\cos A+\sin A)(\cos A-\sin A)$--as you already have--it remains only to somehow rewrite $1-2\sin A\cos A$ as $(\cos A-\sin A)^2$, which can be done by using the Pythagorean identity.